# Jest Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-hooks

I am not sure why jest is failing here. I am calling a custom hook from a component in a service:

```
export function usePolicyDocuments({
  policyReference,
  page = 0,
}: {
  policyReference: string;
  page?: number;
}): Record<string, any> {
  return usePaginatedQuery(
    [`policy.${policyReference}.documents`],
    () => {
      return axios.get(
        `/v1/policies/${policyReference}/documents?page=${page}&size=5`
      );
    },
    {
      enabled: false,
    }
  );
}
```

When a user hovers a button I need them to fire refetch with the updated page index. FYI I am using `react-query` `usePaginatedQuery` with offers `refetch` as a utility to manually get the data.

```
<IconButton
  icon={<FaListUl />}
  aria-label={t('policy-management/view:POPOVER_TRIGGER')}
  variant="solid"
  sx={{
    mx: 'auto',
    fontSize: '1.5rem',
    display: 'flex',
  }}
  onMouseEnter={() => setPageIndex(0)}
/>
```

In my component I trigger `refetch` inside `useEffect` from the `pageIndex`.

```
  const [pageIndex, setPageIndex] = React.useState<number>(-1);
  const {
    resolvedData,
    isFetching,
    status,
    refetch,
  } = policyService.usePolicyDocuments({
    policyReference,
    page: pageIndex,
  });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (pageIndex > -1 && refetch) {
      refetch();
    }
  }, [pageIndex, refetch]);
```

Jest fails with the error:

```
React has detected a change in the order of Hooks
Error: Uncaught [Error: Should have a queue. This is likely a bug in React. Please file an issue.]
   Previous render            Next render
   ------------------------------------------------------
1. useContext                 useContext
2. useState                   useState
3. useRef                     useRef
4. useEffect                  useEffect
5. useState                   useState
6. useEffect                  useReducer
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

How can I get the test to pass?

```
  test('should open the popover', async () => {
    const mock = jest
      .spyOn(policyService, 'usePolicyDocuments')
      .mockImplementationOnce(() => {
        return {
          refetch: jest.fn,
          status: 'loading',
        };
      });
    render(<ReportDetails policyReference="xxx" />);
    const cta = screen.getByRole('button', { name: /POPOVER_TRIGGER/i });
    fireEvent.mouseEnter(cta);
    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(mock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      expect(mock).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ page: -1, policyReference: 'xxx' });
      expect(
        screen.getByText(/DIALOG.HDR.POLICY_DOCUMENTS/i)
      ).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
  });
```

Comment: Since you don't use useReducer yourself, the problem is specific to custom hook that uses it, which is likely usePaginatedQuery here. This lib likely wasn't developed to support test renderer. You didn't specify which one you use which is important, it's likely RTL. Test renderer works differently from real one, this may apply to hooks as well.

Comment: Yes am using react-testing-library.